# How to connect phone data to Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: android, desktop-environments

I connected my Galaxy S9 to Ubuntu via USB, I also enabled "Wifi sharing via USB" in my Androids settings. This "Mobile Network" option appeared on Ubuntu. Clicking and enabling it, apparently is supposed to allow me to use my phones wifi or internet that is connected, but the internet isn't working. Am I using this feature incorrectly? I can't find much about it.

Comment: Which version and flavour of Ubuntu? FYI information, android USB tethering seems to work while you can see a new device that appear. I'll dig your case later, Im interested on it

Comment: Thanks! 19.04 Kubuntu

Comment: If you're connected with USB it's "USB tethering" you want to enable, not WiFi's. For using WiFi tethering your phone creates a wireless hotspot. Connecting to it is no different than connecting to any other WiFi.